# Grunt - not able to minifiy js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am running `grunt` on my app to `jshinting` and `minification`, In which `jshint` is working but the `minification` command not working at all. getting error like this:

```
D:\grunt>grunt min
Warning: Task "min" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

here is my config file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        options: {
            curly: true,
            eqeqeq: true,
            eqnull: true,
            browser: true,
            globals: {
              jQuery: true
            }
        },
      myFiles: ['js/**/*.js']
    },
    min:{
        dest : {
            src:'js/app.js',
            dest:'js/app.min.js'
        }
    },
  });
  // Each plugin must be loaded following this pattern
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

}
```

In this project I have the modules installed is :

`grunt, grunt-contrib-jshint, jshint` - I don't know the wrong what i do..
Any one help me to figure-out the issue please.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minify files you need, for example, uglify.

Install it with this command:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

Then, add it in your Gruntfile

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

Finally, you have to change the code of your Gruntfile:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true,
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      },
    myFiles: ['js/**/*.js']
  },
  uglify:{
    dest : {
        files: {
          'js/app.min.js': ['js/app.js']
        }
    }
  },
});
```

Regards.

Comment: I am getting error like this:

D:\grunt>grunt uglify

D:\grunt\Gruntfile.js:19
                  dest:'js/app.min.js': ['js/app.js']
                                      ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "uglify" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I've removed the "dest:" text. The answers is updated now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a minify task like

```
grunt-contrib-uglify
```

in order to minify the files.

More on [Grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

[Sample Grunt File using uglify](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/02/28/writing-a-simple-grunt-task-using-gruntjs/)

Comment: While you are at it, it can also be worth it to install the watch tasks, so it runs every time you save the file:
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

Comment: `grunt-contrib-uglify` - installed, still not working. getting same error.

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - using npm is those packages need to install?

Comment: @V31 - I am not update the Gruntfile.js - but installed the `grunt-contrib-uglify` - on module folder using npm

Comment: @3gwebtrain added a link where you can get more help on using grunt.